# Assign Reverse Proxy to htaccess

Tags: apache

I am trying to do a revers proxy.

Read some documentation on Apache website and it has pointed me to here: [Apache link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

Reading this section of apache documentation I am trying to use ProxyPass Directive but it does not work

i.e. I want this url :www.example.co.uk/items/footware to be always redirected to this url: www.example.co.uk/footware

HOw do I get this to work using ProxyPass or ProxyPassReverse...?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a case for Proxying - it's a simple [URL rewrite,](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) no?

Comment: Well atualy the example.co.uk is different for the ProxyPassRewrite it has a differentdomain i.e. api.example.co.uk where ProxyPass is example.co.uk two different domains and servers

Comment: Not making any sense, what's the goal in terms of HTTP?